# Is there a way to simulate HC-06 bluetooth module communication with android device, if I don't have the module?

Tags: bluetooth, android

I would like to make an android application which would be able to communicate, through HC-06 bluetooth module, with PIC MCU.

I haven't got the BT modules yet and I would like to prepare the android application. Is there a way to somehow simulate these BT modules?

I just know they use SPP kind of communication. Could I somehow make such communication between 2 android devices using BT? I am really newbie into this so maybe I don't know what am I talking about.

**UPDATE**:
I was able to find a way to do it ([check](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-2-Way-Bluetooth-Connection-Between-Arduino-a/step4/Set-up-your-PC-for-serial-Bluetooth-communication/)). However, Windows 8 somehow doesn't support Bluetooth SPP service. Is there a way to enable SPP for Windows bluetooth?

Comment: This would probably get better answers on the android stack exchange.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can start a serial port profile communication between two android devices. But I'd be shocked if the android sdk doesn't have a way to simulate incoming serial messages,  it's just plain text ascii.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try to post it on android stack exchange, and good to know that it is just a text ascii :).

Comment: Just Google "Android bluetooth spp" and you'll get a bunch of examples to work of I of for now

Comment: No idea, try again, I think it was a good idea.

Comment: Apparently android dev questions belong on Stack Overflow according to the Android Stack.

Comment: AFAIK opened BT channel is common TCP socket, so You can create server socket on PC, redirect serial port stream to this socket (use serial-tcp redirector http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector ), and access it from Android over WiFi/Ethernet/USB.